# Difference between if(a==b) vs if(!(a!=b))

Tags: c#, performance

I have come across some code snippet in our project.
The old guy replaced

```
if(!this.printHelper.PrepareDoc(printerName, report, this.PageBox != null)){
    return;
}
```

with

```
if(this.printHelper.PrepareDoc(printerName, report, this.PageBox == null)){
    return;
}
```

for performance improvement.
What is the actual difference between these two condition?

Comment: How can we tell without seeing `PrepareDoc`?

Comment: I don't see a performance improvement but I do see more readability. The performance improvement might be in `.PrepareDoc`

Comment: Your code is quite different from "a==b" vs "!(a!=b)" since it changes the third parameter to PrepareDoc().

Answer (score 3):

The two statements are completely different.

`this.PageBox != null` evaluates to a `boolean`, and you are flipping that value in the parameter list, and conditioning on the opposite *return* value.

They *might* have gotten away with this if the function return value is the value of the third parameter passed in, or a negation of it.

Comment: Unless PrepareDoc was also changed ... in which case the question needs replacing.

Comment: 'The old guy needs replacing' is very speculative. We don't know what `PrepareDoc` is affected by.

Comment: Maybe the new guy needs replacing :D

Comment: @Ped7g: True, they just don't make them like they used to.

Comment: Let's not take chances, replace *all* the guys.

Comment: @Bathsheba Nope, I do not.

Comment: @Rotem: They'd like your idea.

Comment: @Bathsheba Apologies, your rhetorical was lost on me.

Answer (score 0):

These two statements are logically completely different!

The first statement if block will only execute if false as you are inverting 'logical NOT' the boolean returned by your function call **PrepareDoc** and the second statement will only execute if true.

Also, the final parameter on the first statement is inverted / flipped and so the value passed to the function call **PrepareDoc** is the logical inverse.

The only performance difference will be the operation of flipping the return value of the function on the first statement and the parameter.